# justify-content does not work in CSS grid in my code

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3.2rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 6.4rem;
  row-gap: 8.6rem;
}

.grid-2-cols {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.step-img {
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid grid-2-cols grid-center">
  <div class="step-text-box">
    <p>01</p>
    <p>Tell us what you like (and what not)</p>
    <p>
      Never again waste time thinking about what to eat! Omnifood AI will create a 100% personalized weekly meal plan just for you. It makes sure you get the nutrients and vitamins you need, no matter what diet you follow!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="step-img-box">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1JJVhy2/app-screen-1.png" alt="Omnifood iPhone app" class="step-img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In .grid-center selector, align-items works properly, but justify-content just does not work

Why is this and how to solve it? Can anyone solve my puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **display flex** in .grid-center selector:

```
.grid-center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: the following CSS]

Answer (score 0):

Align-items and justify-content works with element that has `display: flex;`. I think that `align-items: center` *seems* to work because of `margin: 0 auto;` in .container class because it centers the content.